# Samsung CLX-3170 prints faded pages and horizontal lines

Tags: printing, laser-printer

I've got an old Samsung CLX-3170 printer and it's acting up. The first page is usually decent, but the contents of page 1 will transfer to the second page in light grey (faded). It also prints vertical lines randomly on certain pages. Below are the counters provided by the WebUI. Is it time to replace the entire printer or is it worth the money to fix it somehow? I would have to replace all toners pretty soon too...

```
Total Page Count :     8998 / 4324 Page(s) (Color/Mono)
Toner Page Count :     ( Yellow / Magenta / Cyan / Black )( 1262 / 1251 / 1243 / 234 ) Page(s)
Fuser Life :           40100 Page(s)
Transfer Roller Life : 13254 Page(s)
Tray Roller Life :     13322 Page(s)
Total Image Count :    40387 Image(s)
Imaging Unit Life :    18545 Image(s)
Transfer Belt Life :   40387 Image(s)
```

***I ended up replacing both the transfer belt and the drum and all is good!***

Comment: Clean the print head (search for how). Otherwise, replace the ink, but is it worth this investment?

Comment: A vertical line will almost certainly be the drum. Have you replaced the drum, roller and toner?